# Marking small width in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I just want to ask how to label the width of the strip with arrows and marded as shown in jpg.

There is some problem with xticklabel spacing as well. They are up down.

I have attached the complete running script. kindly help.

Regards

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    axis lines =middle,
    hide y axis, 
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    x axis line style={draw opacity=1},
    ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
    xtick={-0.5,0.25},
    xticklabels={$x$, $x+\delta x$},
    axis on top,
    ] 
\addplot[ultra thick, color=orange,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};

\addplot+[ultra thick, mark=none,
    domain=-0.5:0.25,
    samples=100,
    pattern=flexible hatch,
    area legend,
    pattern color=red]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
```

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just draw the arrows using the `axis direction cs`. Note that I also switched to `patterns.meta`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    axis lines =middle,
    hide y axis, 
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    x axis line style={draw opacity=1},
    ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
    xtick={-0.5,0.25},
    xticklabels={$x\vphantom{\delta}$, $x+\delta x$},
    axis on top,
    ] 
\addplot[ultra thick, color=orange,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};

\addplot+[ultra thick, mark=none,
    domain=-0.5:0.25,
    samples=100,
    pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={5pt}]},
    area legend,
    pattern color=red]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;
    \draw[stealth-,thick] (0.25,0.1) -- ++ (axis direction cs:0.5,0)
    node[above]{$\delta x$};
    \draw[stealth-,thick] (-0.5,0.1) -- ++ (axis direction cs:-0.5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use the `fillbetween` library here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
    axis lines =middle,
    hide y axis, 
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    x axis line style={draw opacity=1},
    ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
    xtick={-0.5,0.25},
    xticklabels={$x\vphantom{\delta}$, $x+\delta x$},
    axis on top,
    ] 
\addplot[name path=A,ultra thick, color=orange,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
\path [name path=B] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot+[ultra thick, mark=none,
    pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={5pt}]},
    pattern color=red,draw=red]
    fill between [of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-0.5:0.25}];
    \draw[stealth-,thick] (0.25,0.1) -- ++ (axis direction cs:0.5,0)
    node[above]{$\delta x$};
    \draw[stealth-,thick] (-0.5,0.1) -- ++ (axis direction cs:-0.5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `\vphantom` simply use the `axis` option `typeset ticklabels with strut`.

Comment: Thanks Schrondinger's cat bulls eye exactly want this. Obliged.